# Is it necessary to have a PRIMARY index AND colname index on the primary key column?

Tags: mysql, indexing, ems

Imagine the following table:

Simple single row table.

Colname = id int(11)

```
+---------------------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table               | Non_unique | Key_name | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+---------------------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| tablename           |          0 | PRIMARY  |            1 | id          | A         |     1719077 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| tablename           |          0 | id       |            1 | id          | A         |     1719077 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
+---------------------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
```

That is the dump of show indexes in tablename.

I think this is a 'bug' in the mysql manager I use (ems mysql manager) where when you create a table with a primary key, it will create both a PRIMARY index (the name of the actual index is PRIMARY) and also a primary-key-colname index automatically on table creation.

Is it ok to remove one of these?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely. The primary key will function just fine as an index.

Comment: Check out [pt-duplicate-key-checker](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/pt-duplicate-key-checker.html) if you ever want to see if you have unneeded indices.